# « [...] le nombre de défauts trouvé(s) [...] » : avec ou sans « s » ?

Tags: accord, pluriel

J'ai demandé a pas mal de monde et personne ne semble être d'accord. Pour la phrase suivante, le mot « trouvé » prend-il un « s » ?

> Les chercheurs ont relevé le nombre de défauts trouvé(s) par le client avant et après la mise en application de la méthode.

J'aurais tendance à l'accorder avec « défauts » mais certaines personnes à qui j'ai demandé pensent qu'il faut l'accorder avec « nombre » ou encore « client ».

Comment: L'accord ne peut certainement pas se fait faire avec « client ». Es-tu sûr que tu ne voulais pas demander si l'accord se fait avec « nombre » ou « défauts »   ?

Comment: @Laure J'ai édité ma question. Selon la personne à qui je demande j'ai soit accord avec « défauts », « client » ou « nombre ». Bref, personne n'est d'accord.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'accord ne peut absolument pas se faire avec client. L'adjectif ne peut s'accorder qu'avec le nom qu'il qualifie. Ce n'est pas le client qui est « trouvé », il est celui qui trouve les défauts.

Ce qu'il faut donc se demander c'est si le client trouve le **nombre de défauts** ou **les défauts**. Pour moi il est clair que ce sont les défauts qui sont trouvés par le client, donc tu as raison. Une fois tous les défauts trouvés il pourra éventuellement les compter, mais seulement une fois qu'il les aura tous trouvés.

> Les chercheurs ont relevé le nombre de défauts trouv**és** par le client avant et après la mise en application de la méthode.

Comment: C'est déjà plus clair, merci. Cependant, si je comprend bien cela signifie que « trouvé » sans « s » n'est pas nécessairement une erreur dans le cas où on parle du nombre ?

Comment: @Ren Dans ce cas c'est le sens qui dicte l'accord, on comprend bien que ce sont les défauts qui sont trouvés par le client et que le chercheur fait le compte. Comparons « le nombre de défauts élevé » (c'est le nombre qui est élevé) et le « nombre de défauts trouvés ».

Comment: D’accord je vois, merci !

Answer (score 3):

Le problème vient de ce que *trouvé* et *trouvés* se prononcent exactement de la même manière.  Si on remplace *défauts* (masculin) par un nom féminin, mettons *erreurs*, et *trouvé* par *fait*, on dira :

- Les chercheurs ont relevé le nombre d'erreurs faites par le client avant et après la mise en application de la méthode.

On entend que l'adjectif s'accorde avec le nom qui le précède, comme dans la phrase que tu proposes, on a donc :

- Les chercheurs ont relevé le nombre de défauts trouvés par le client avant et après la mise en application de la méthode

Comment: Merci pour ta réponse, l'exemple est bien trouvé et je n'avais pas penser à remplacer les mots ! Comme je ne peux accepter qu'une seule réponse, je vais choisir celle de Laure car elle m'a mieux aider à comprendre comment ce fait l'accord.

Comment: La méthode de la substitution  par un adj. ou p.p. se terminant par une consonne avec accord au féminin ne marche que si le locuteur a déjà « une oreille » bien formée. Ce qui n'est pas souvent le cas avec des locuteurs non natifs et beaucoup de natifs aussi ne seraient pas choqués par, ou pourraient dire : « les chercheurs ont relevé le nombre d'erreurs fait par le client ».

Comment: @Laure         C'est vrai.  On ne sait rien de Ren, mais vu la qualité du français qu'il utilise, je suis parti du principe qu'il - elle ? - était francophone et que ce petit point de désaccord concernait un groupe de francophones.  Quant à l'accord avec "nombre", si on reprend ton explication, que je trouve très bonne, le client fait les erreurs et pas le nombre.  En toute logique, il faudrait accorder avec "erreurs".